# CSS3 | Почему увеличение кнопки не плавное, а резкое?

Tags: css3

Я на **VueJS** снова хотел сделать тот же экперемент, только с другими стилями. Это обычный счётчик, там я тренерую **CSS** навыки. И вот почти готово, я добавил плавное изменение цвета, всё замечательно. Вот только ширина не хочет **плавно** увеличиваться. Помогите пожалуйста. Вот код:

```css
div {
  margin: auto;
  position: relative;
  text-align: center;
}
div > h1 {
  font-family: "Segoe UI", Tahoma, Geneva, Verdana, sans-serif;
}
.btn {
  padding: 10px 30px 10px 30px;
  margin: 0px 15px 0px 15px;
  font-size: 24px;
  font-weight: 500;
  font-family: "Gill Sans", "Gill Sans MT", Calibri, "Trebuchet MS", sans-serif;
  outline: none;
  border: 3px solid #333;
  border-radius: 30px;
  transition-property: all;
  transition-duration: 0.4s;
  transition-timing-function: ease;
  cursor: pointer;
}
.increment {
  background-color: #3f3;
}
.increment:hover {
  background-color: #afa;
  width: 200px;
}
.decrement {
  background-color: #f33;
}
.decrement:hover {
  background-color: #faa;
  width: 200px;
}
```

```html
<div>
    <h1>
      Your count is <span>0</span>
    </h1>
    <hr />
    <div>
      <button class="btn increment">Increment</button>
      <button class="btn decrement">Decrement</button>
    </div>
</div>
```

Как сделать чтобы при наводке курсора на кнопку она плавно увеличивалась?

Comment: У вас нет начальной ширины. https://css-tricks.com/using-css-transitions-auto-dimensions/

Comment: Анимация от/к значению auto не работает.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Как уже говорилась в комментариях, чтобы добиться плавного изменения размеров при наведении на элемент, необходимо задать начальное и конечное значение ширины.

Однако, в вашем случае для кнопки я бы не рекомендовал так делать. Погонять ширину кнопки будет сложно, учитывая, что один и тот же шрифт у разных пользователей может отображаться по-разному, и у кого-то текст кнопки может выходить за ее пределы или обрезаться при минимальном значении ее ширины.

Как более правильный вариант, предлагаю использовать внутренний отступ `padding`. Вот пример:

```css
div {
  margin: auto;
  position: relative;
  text-align: center;
}

div>h1 {
  font-family: "Segoe UI", Tahoma, Geneva, Verdana, sans-serif;
}

.btn {
  padding: 10px 30px 10px 30px;
  margin: 0px 15px 0px 15px;
  font-size: 24px;
  font-weight: 500;
  font-family: "Gill Sans", "Gill Sans MT", Calibri, "Trebuchet MS", sans-serif;
  outline: none;
  border: 3px solid #333;
  border-radius: 30px;
  transition-property: all;
  transition-duration: 0.4s;
  transition-timing-function: ease;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.increment {
  background-color: #3f3;
}

.increment:hover {
  background-color: #afa;
  padding: 10px 60px 10px 60px;
}

.decrement {
  background-color: #f33;
}

.decrement:hover {
  background-color: #faa;
  padding: 10px 60px 10px 60px;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <h1>
    Your count is <span>0</span>
  </h1>
  <hr />
  <div>
    <button class="btn increment">Increment</button>
    <button class="btn decrement">Decrement</button>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Cпасибо! Как вы сказали что нет **начальной ширины**, то понял, что отталкиваться плавному увеличению нечем.